# Locate 3 html div in different height 1st on left, 2nd and 3rd on the right

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I use bootstrap and want to locate three div's as shown below.
Could you please give a sample demo that can meet this requirement? 
If it is possible, it would be better to use bootstrap.css?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Html:**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="http://usebootstrap.com/" class="navbar-brand">UseBootstrap</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:325px !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title">AAAAAAAAAAAAAA<a href="#panel-title" class="anchorjs-link"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Content AAAAAAAA
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:325px !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB<a href="#panel-title" class="anchorjs-link"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Content BBBBBBBBBBB
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:325px !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC<a href="#panel-title" class="anchorjs-link"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Content CCCCCCCCCCC
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="height:325px !important;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" id="panel-title">DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD<a href="#panel-title" class="anchorjs-link"><span class="anchorjs-icon"></span></a></h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Content DDDDDDDDDDD
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8098/ like this?

Comment: @Amit Thanks for reply, but not like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
<header class="row"></header>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="row"></footer>
```

Actually, here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid everything is written and I recommend you to read it before asking questions next time)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code;

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#header,
#footer {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
#lhs {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 300px;
}
#rhs1,
#rhs2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#rhs2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
      <div class="container" id="header">
        Header
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div id="lhs">
          left hand side
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div id="rhs1">
          Right hand side Up
          </div>
          <div id="rhs2">
          Right hand side Down
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div class="container" id="footer">
        Footer
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not want to use table and for this reason I applied the code of mankutila. Nevertheless, I voted up+

Comment: Thank you so much,
but this is a bootstrap grid system not table :)
Regards

Comment: Sorry, I just copied my answer given to above :)

Answer (score 1):

This goes to `rowspan`, as far as `display:table` doesn't support `rowspan` property for me best solution is to use our old friend `table`

here take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/myzL761q/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not want to use table and for this reason I applied the code of mankutila. Nevertheless, I voted up+